# cd-command not operating even with capitalized letters used in bash

Tags: command-line, bash, cd-command

Hey everyone I need help with my cd command as it is not working. I typed:

```
cd Downloads
```

and it won't work, I'm trying to install something and it's giving me this as a response.

```
-bash: cd: Downloads: No such file or directory
```

Any help would be appreciated and please be gentle lol

Comment: Try running `ls -l` to se what directories there are, and also `pwd` to see which directory you are in now.

Comment: as @SorenA mentioned doing an `ls -l` and/or `pwd` will tell you about the current directory structure. As the error already says that `cd` it self is working by giving the error that there is no such file or directory.

Answer (score 1):

Check if a Downloads directory exists in your home directory. If you are a root user your terminal prompt is a `#` character, so exit back to normal user by running `exit` and your terminal prompt will change from a `#` character to a `$` character. Then run the following commands.

```
cd  
ls
```

Make a Downloads directory if it doesn't exist and change directories to it.

```
cd # Change directories to your home directory.
mkdir Downloads # Make a Downloads directory if it doesn't exist.
cd Downloads
```